# jquery dialog .html() question

Tags: jquery, html, dialog, external

I am using a jquery dialog and want to set the .html value with an external html file located on the same server. What I'm unsure of is exactly how to achieve this.

```
var $tos_dlg = $('<div></div>')
  .html($(this).load('/includes/tos.html'))
  .dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    title: 'Policies &amp; Terms of Service',
    width: 600,
    height: 400,
    modal: true
});
```

The above section where the .html() is called is where I want to inject the contents of the external file. I think that the .load function would work somehow, but just not sure if that is the right approach and if so, how exactly to implement it. Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Call `.load()` on `$tos_dlg` directly:

```
var $tos_dlg = $('<div></div>')
    .load('/includes/tos.html')
    .dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        title: 'Policies &amp; Terms of Service',
        width: 600,
        height: 400,
        modal: true
    });
```

Also, make sure you are attaching `$tos_dlg` to the DOM somewhere, via something like `$tos_dlg.appendTo("#containerElement")`.

Comment: Outstanding! That was the perfect solution! Thank you ever so much, gilly3!

Comment: Pardon my asking, but what does that do or is it needed for? The appendTo() that is.

Comment: Use append or appendTo to insert new content into the page. You created a new <div> element with `$("<div>")`. You can work with that new element all you want, but it won't appear in your page until you put it there. The syntax is either `existingContent.append(newContent)` or `newContent.appendTo(existingContent)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var $tos_dlg = $('<div></div>').html($(this).load('/includes/tos.html'));
$("body").append($tos_dlg);
$tos_dlg.dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    title: 'Policies &amp; Terms of Service',
    width: 600,
    height: 400,
    modal: true
});
```

Comment: I did try this, but I either did something wrong or it didn't work. When I came back here to try checking the code, gilly3's answer was here and that worked perfectly, but thank you for your great suggestion.